# IdentityServer4 with a .Net Core Web App Javascript Single Page Application - Should I use oidc-client on front end or carry actions out in backend?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I work on an a legacy .net core 3.1 Web App which is solely used to serve static javascript files to the browser build with knockout.js and calling a Web API.

At present, the API is also bundled into this one web application, and I'd like to add in IdentityServer4 authentication to this application.

My question is, because this is a JavaScript app (although built on top of a .net core web app), should I be following the 'Adding a JavaScript client' documentation, or the MVC app documentation on the identity server documentation website?

I've tried to go down the MVC application route and I can login fine and get redirected back to the application but I get CORS errors for logout due to me making an ajax call to my API to initiate the logout with the SignOut("Cookies", "oidc"); method. The CORS error that I get after attempting logout is as follows: "CORS request made for path: /Account/Logout from origin: null but was ignored because path was not for an allowed IdentityServer CORS endpoint".

Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You have two places to configure CORS with IdentityServer. First you define the allowed CORS endpoints in the IdentityServer client definitions. But this is only applied for requests to IdentityServer itself.

Then you also need to configure CORS in ASP.NET Core for all non-IdentityServer related requests.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already added all 'AllowedCorsOrigins' for my client and also have added Cors policies to the startup file of the .Net Core Web App that is trying to communicate to my Identity Server project to initiate logout - but I still receive a CORS error when trying to log out.

Comment: Are you running your page from local disk? (File://....)? When you get origin Null then that is a common reason. I would use a tool like Fiddler and look a the web traffic, and perhaps post the CORS interaction in your question here so we can better troubleshoot it.